# Data obfuscation strategies that keep statistical properties intact

Tags: r, data-transformation, dataset

I am getting data from a provider that contains identifiable information from a number of different organizations. The data aren't particularly sensitive, but to be safe, the provider wants to perform some obfuscation techniques on the continuous variables.  I want to make sure ahead of time that these strategies will not problematize interpretation or analysis of the variables of interest.

Two potential ideas:

- Mean centering the values prior to be given them
- Adding random noise to every observation

Are there better solutions?  The issue with mean centering is that it makes interpretation more difficult if the mean-centered variable is a DV, as you can't recover the true mean of the distribution.   Random noise also clearly has its drawbacks as it will increase the variance of the estimates.

Comment: It depends on the analysis you want to make. (linear) Regression might not be affected (in theory) by adding random noise, but calculating the variance of the data will be affected. Can maybe the labels, row and column names be randomized/masked? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_masking lists many other potential methods.

Comment: @Denwid, ah of course the variance will be affected.  Good call.  Unfortunately, we need all the column names as the purpose is to have interpretable results.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: SMOTE is used to create synthethic data with the same properties as your original data. I don't know how safe it is though, that is if someone can reverse engineer the data.

Comment: "Adding random noise to every observation (shouldn't effect regressions)" --- it will definitely affect regressions, even the estimates of coefficients. If you add noise to predictors, estimates will be biased, for one thing.

Comment: Have a look at the differential privacy literature.

Comment: @Björn, seems like a pretty substantial literature.  Are you referencing something in particular.

Comment: @Glen_b, thanks Glen! Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The area isn't really something I have much expertise on; but I'd have given the same advice as Björn. If I was in your shoes, that's exactly the literature I would be reading.